# C# 'for' keyword used as method input

Tags: c#

I came across this code excerpt but the syntax is unknown to me:

```cs
public void Execute(EvaluateAutomaticActions cmd)
{
    if (GetUnreadMessagesCount(for: AssignedAgent) > 0)
    {
        _agent = AssignNewAgent();
    }
}

public int GetUnreadMessagesCount(UserId id)
{
    return _messages.Where(x => x.To == id && !x.WasRead).Count();
}
```

How is the 'for' keyword supposed to work on the third line? Does this syntax have a name?

Comment: thats a named parameter

Comment: look at the signature for the `GetUnreadMessagesCount` method

Comment: where's the code excerpt from? can you provide a [mcve]

Comment: @DanielA.White It is from a book named 'Learning Domain-Driven Design', sorry that is all there is in the example. I edited my answer to provide the `GetUnreadMessagesCount` method but there is nothing more.

Comment: That looks like invalid code to me.

Comment: yep now it looks invalid as well. originally it was a named parameter

Comment: what code sample is it? i found the github

Comment: `GetUnreadMessagesCount(id: AssignedAgent)`  would make sense(\*) if `AssignedAgent` was a `UserId` - (*) not sure why one would explicitly name the single param though

Comment: Ok thanks for the confirmation. I wanted to be sure since I'm not proficient in C#. I guess I'll submit an Errata then.

Comment: @DanielA.White https://github.com/vladikk/learning-ddd/blob/main/listings/06-13.cs

Comment: So to be sure, this 'for' keyword is only supposed to be a variable name and have nothing to do with the 'for loop'? Its looks weird to me that the compiler allows you to name your variables after keywords like this in C#.

Comment: There are a handful of "contextual keywords" in C# that are allowed as identifiers so as to not break compatibility with programs that might have used them that way before they were added to the language (for example, `async`). `for` is not one of those, however, and cannot be used as an identifier unless it's escaped (`@for`). So this is not legal C# in any case -- and as the example shows, it is not a case of a named parameter (since the parameter's name is actually `id`). Unless there's some sort of preprocessor involved, this won't compile. If it's pseudocode, it's needlessly confusing.